# How to read the interface name from a .pcapng file using tshark?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, packet-capture, tshark, pcap-ng

I am trying to run this `tshark` command :

`tshark -r $file -T fields -E separator=/t -e frame.number -e frame.time -e frame.protocols -e frame.len -e frame.interface_id -e frame.interface_name`

I get this warning :

`** (process:30955): WARNING **: 'frame.interface_name' isn't a valid field!
tshark: Some fields aren't valid`

But I am able to see the field when I open the file in `Wireshark` ?

What is the right way to access the interface_name info?

I am using the following tshark version -

```
TShark 1.12.1 (Git Rev Unknown from unknown)

Copyright 1998-2014 Gerald Combs <gerald@wireshark.org> and contributors.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Compiled (64-bit) with GLib 2.32.4, with libpcap, with libz 1.2.7, with POSIX
capabilities (Linux), with libnl 3, with SMI 0.4.8, with c-ares 1.9.1, with Lua
5.2, without Python, with GnuTLS 2.12.20, with Gcrypt 1.5.0, with MIT Kerberos,
with GeoIP.

Running on Linux 3.16.7-cb2000v1, with locale en_US.UTF-8, with libpcap version
1.3.0, with libz 1.2.7.
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v4 @ 2.40GHz

Built using gcc 4.7.2.
```

I tried updating wireshark -

`$ sudo apt-get install wireshark
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
wireshark is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 isc-dhcp-relay : Depends: isc-dhcp-common (= 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u8) but 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u8 is to be installed
 isc-dhcp-server : Depends: isc-dhcp-common (= 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u8) but 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u8 is to be installed
 libsnmp-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.14.2-21+deb7u5) but 5.14.2-21+deb7u3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

It says `wireshark is already the newest version`.

This is the linux OS details of the machine : 
`Distributor ID:    Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:    7.8
Codename:   wheezy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) are you using?  Run `tshark -v` to check.

The **frame.interface_name** display filter is only available beginning with version 2.4.0, so maybe you have an older version of `tshark` in your `%PATH%`?

Note that you can check for the availability of any display filter on the Wireshark [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/) Page.

Comment: I have updated the question with the details you have asked for. Yes the tshark version is 1.2.1. But it is not allowing update. It say's `wireshark is already the newest version`
And you are right the tshark version on my local desktop is 2.6.6. And that is allowing the filter to be applied if I down the .pcapng file onto my local desktop and run the original command. What can I do to force the wireshark update on the remote Debian machine?

Comment: I primarily work on the Windows platform so I'm unfamiliar with how Debian updates work.  If you can't find a way to download a package, you might be able to just download the Wireshark sources, then compile and install Wireshark yourself.  In that case, you may wish to have a look at the Wireshark Developer's Guide: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/